# Re-rendering a component when a prop value changes after initial render (Vue 3)

Tags: vuejs3

Heyo,

I am trying to create a component that behaves in a particular way.

What I want to have happen is the child component to initially render with the prop it is given, but when the prop is updated (through another component emitting a value), the component should re-render with the new prop.

Currently, the following code accomplishes half of what I want. It fails to render what is passed into the prop the first time for the initial render but successfully re-renders when an updated prop is passed through.

I can accomplish the other half of what I want when I remove the `this.$watch` function, but I can't seem to get both pieces of desired functionality to work at the same time.

```
<template>
    <div class="progressDisplay">
        <div class="progressBar" ref="progressBar">
            <div class="coverCircle">
                <div class="valueContainer" ref="valueContainer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ProgressCircle',
        props: {
            endvalue: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            
            
        },
        computed: {

        },
        mounted() {
            this.$watch( 'endvalue', ( newEndValue ) => {
                let progressBar = this.$refs.progressBar;
                let valueContainer = this.$refs.valueContainer;

                let progressValue = 0;
                let speed = 10;

                let progress = setInterval(() => {
                    if ( newEndValue < 0 ) {
                        valueContainer.innerText = '---';
                        clearInterval( progress );
                    } else {
                        if ( this.newEndValue !== 0 ) {
                            progressValue++;
                        }
                        valueContainer.innerText = `${ progressValue }%`;
                        if ( progressValue >= 100 ) {
                            valueContainer.style.color = 'green';
                            progressBar.style.background = 'green';
                        } else {
                            valueContainer.style.color = 'black';
                            progressBar.style.background = `conic-gradient( 
                                #192A44 ${ progressValue * 3.6}deg,
                                #EEEEEE ${ progressValue * 3.6}deg
                                )`
                        }
                    }
                    if ( progressValue === this.endvalue ) {
                        clearInterval( progress );
                    }
                }, speed);
            })
            
        },
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .progressDisplay {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    }

    .progressBar {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -8px -2px 3x -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -8px -2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    box-shadow: inset -8px -2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.068);
    }

    .coverCircle {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -8px -2px 43px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    -moz-box-shadow: -8px -2px 43px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    box-shadow: -8px -2px 2px -rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.077);
    }

    .valueContainer {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 500;
    }
</style>
```

I am not sure if there what I am doing is on the right path or if I am just missing something.

Comment: Your desired behavior should be default for [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow).  How are you checking the initial/updated prop values? [vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/)?  The only thing that sticks out to me is the `watch` being inside `mounted`. That's not typical. [Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example) are usually created as their own component property, e.g. `computed: { ... }, mounted() { ... }, watch: { ... },`. It might also help to show how youre updating your props in the parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the `updated()` lifecycle hook to re-render this component after the initial render.

Not sure if this was the most optimal way to do this but it works